# Trying to sort sections in descending order

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
        self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        BOOL found;
        for (NSDictionary *wine in sortedWines)
        {
            NSNumber *rate = [wine valueForKey:@"Rate"];
            NSString *rateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [rate floatValue]];
            found = NO;
            for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
            {
                if ([str isEqualToString:rateStr])
                {
                    found = YES;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {[self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:rateStr];}
        }
        for (NSDictionary *wine in sortedWines)
        {[[self.sections objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [[wine valueForKey:@"Rate"] floatValue]] ] addObject:wine];}

        // Sort:
        for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
        {[[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Rate" ascending:NO]]];}
```

This code puts my wines in sections, but it won't sort them in descending order! Could it be because the NSNumber is transformed into NSString? I've tried to make a code using the NSNumber value:

```
        self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        BOOL found;
        for (NSDictionary *wine in sortedWines)
        {
            NSNumber *rate = [wine valueForKey:@"Rate"];
            found = NO;
            for (NSNumber *str in [self.sections allKeys])
            {
                if ([str isEqualToNumber:rate])
                {
                    found = YES;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {[self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:rate];}
        }
        // Loop again to sort wines into their keys
        for (NSDictionary *wine in sortedWines)
        {[[self.sections objectForKey:[wine valueForKey:@"Rate"]] addObject:wine];}

        // Sort each section array
        for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
        {[[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Rate" ascending:NO]]];}
```

But it gives a warning for

```
if (!found)
{[self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:rate];}
```

that says "Incompatible pointer types sending NSNumber ___strong to parameter of type NSString"

If I run the app it crashes with error `-[__NSCFNumber localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e085810`

What do I have to change to make it work and sort the sections in descending order? Thanks.

Comment: Well I guess using NSSortDescriptors to sort all the keys in the way you want is better. Just sort them using your criteria and get the objects out of the dictionary in order.

Comment: It looks like that second method should have worked -- I don't understand either error. Try logging [rate class] to make sure it's an NSNumber. Are you sure that first error is on the line you think it is? As for the second error, I don't know where the caseInsensitiveCompare came from.  Did you set that somewhere? I thought the selector for that method was just compare: (and it should use NSNumber's version of compare: if you pass it to an NSNumber).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the default selector for sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending: is now caseInsensitiveCompare:, I'm pretty sure it used to be just compare:. In any case, you can use sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector:, instead, and pass compare: for the selector. I think that should fix your second error. Still not sure why you're getting that first error.

Answer (score 1):

You would do much better (and we'd understand you better) if you formatted your code for legibility.  Eg:

```
    // Loop again to sort wines into their keys
    for (NSDictionary *wine in sortedWines) {
        NSArray* section = [self.sections objectForKey:[wine valueForKey:@"Rate"]];
        [section addObject:wine];
    }

    // Sort each section array
    NSArray* sortDescriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Rate" ascending:NO]];
    for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys]) {
         NSArray* section = [self.sections objectForKey:key];
         [section sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];
    }
```

Among other things, this makes debugging much simpler since you can stop and dump the `section` arrays.

Or, if you really liked it better the other way, I can highly recommend that you learn APL or LISP instead.